# how do i execute function when all my thread finished in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, promise

i want to implement multiple threads at same time to get restful services data. And i want to show the activity when all threads completed like in promise based applications.

Comment: Too broad, voting to close. http://developer.android.com/ has lots of this kind of tutorial. Check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Use queue library to execute all jobs with the same key that will make jobs to execute in queue, at the last job call back show your activity.

Recommended library :

[JobQueue](https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue)

Comment: i don't think it has any type of callback when thread completes.

Comment: U can use event bus lib for call back

Comment: correct me if i am getting it write here, But there is no override method in there which  will be called when job will be done.

Comment: When onRun method finished without any exception job will be finished so if you want to notify your  activity you can use eventbus